# VUE on-changed checked and ajax request

Tags: ajax, vue.js, v-model

Im using bootstrap vue:

```
<b-form-checkbox @change="onoff('concurency_filter')" v-model="concurency_filter.onoff" switch size="lg"></b-form-checkbox>
```

And I need call ajax with state of this checkbox:

```
onoff: function (filter) {
  axios.put('/api/user/accounts/'+this.account_id+'/togglefilter',
   {
       filter: filter,
       status: this[filter].onoff //here still old value in this.concurency_filter.onoff
  }).then(response => {
    ..........
  });
},
```

But v-model still not changed when ajax is called. When checkbox clicked v-model must toggle true/false, but ajax called before v-model toggle it. How to deal with it?

I know that I can use WATCH in vue, but when first time ajax loading data it's triggering this WATCH event. I want trigger it only on click

Answer (score 1):

**Success:**

```
onoff('concurency_filter', $event)
```

$event will contain exact value of checkbox right after click